# Solution of $T(n)=2T(n/2)+\log(\log n))$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I need to solve $T(n)=2T(n/2)+\log(\log n))$ using the master theorem.

I tried $m=\log n$ so $2^m=n$ and then:

$T(2^m)=2T(2^m/2)+\log m$ and so if $S(m)=T(2^m)$ then $S(m)=2S(m-1)+\log m$.

But then I can't use the the Master Theorem.
Is there another $m$ I can choose to get what I want? Or some other trick I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the master theorem on the original recurrence?

Answer (score 0):

With your substitution, the solution to the recurrence is $$f(m) = \sum_{i=1}^m 2^{m-i} \log(m-i)$$ which, according to Mathematica equals

$$-2^{n-1}
   \text{HurwitzLerchPhi}^{(0,1,0)}\left(\frac{1}{2},0,1-n\right)+\text{PolyLog}^{(1,0)}\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)+i \pi  \left(2^n-1\right)$$

Not super enlightening.